# Translate Physical Path to VIrtual Path in PHP

Tags: php

I'm returning HTML (which includes IMG SRC attributes) from my php scripts and I cannot make any assumption for the absolute directory structure. I can make relative references.

Suppose my directory looks like this on my machine:

/abc/php.php

/abc/img/1.png

Now this may be hosted on some server as:

/xyz/php.php

/xyz/img/1.png

I need my `<img src="???">` and `<form action="???">` such at it works in both cases. That is I need to figure out how to reference `1.png` from `php.php` such that it works irrespective of where the site is hosted.

I cannot use something like `src="/img/some.png"` because that is absolute from `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. I cannot make any assumption about where relative to the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` my script is hosted. How should I reference resources in HTML without assuming path from `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Basically, I'm looking for the reverse of `realpath` and I'm working with pure php not using any frameworks.

**PS:** This may sound like a duplicate, but I have spent a better part of the last two hours looking for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the solution used by wordpress in which the absolute path is defined by the user in the configuration section (if such a section exists) or inside a config file.
Then I define a function like this:

```
function base($tail = ''){
    global $config;
    echo 'http://',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],'/',$config['path'],'/',$tail;
}
```

Comment: And `$config` is an array defined in a php file, which is included in every php file where you need the definition? Sorry, I'm pretty new to server side programming.

Comment: Yes, that would be the definition.

Answer (score 1):

This function returns takes any physical path and translate it to virtual one :

```
 function get_virtual_path($physical_path) {
        $physical_path = str_replace('\\', '/', $physical_path);  
        $document_root_path = str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
        $path=  str_replace($document_root_path, "", $physical_path);
        $http = isset($_SERVER ['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        return  $http . $host . $path; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know they will be deployed in the same filesystem tree then it's possible to search upwards to find a directory named 'img'

```
function get_top_dir($currdir, $search)
{
   if (file_exists($currdir . '/' . $search)) {
      return $currdir;
   }
   if (dirname($currdir)===$currdir) {
      trigger_error("not found");
      return false;
   }
   return get_top_dir(dirname($currdir), $search);
}
```

then map it to a relative URL based on the filename of the current script or an absolute URL based on the filename and URL of the current script. The code for this would be a bit more complicated.

But in practice its a lot simpler to just use a config file.