# Dynamic URL Sub Folders

Tags: php, dynamic

**I need this script to do something pretty simple.**

I work from localhost, then upload. I need the directory returned to be dynamic. For it to grab the proper url even if it has multiple sub-folders.

Where it says

> $baseurl = $protocol . $host . "/websites/andrewhunter/";

What I need is if you are downloading or uploading the site, the script knows the proper url. Right now what is being used for the hosting environment is a sub-directory. So domain.com/websites/client_website and this cannot be changed.

So basically I can't get it to work right. I've tried a few methods and this is the closed method by echoing a base url on all pages where needed.

**It does not grab the folder above it or dynamically adjust to the domain.com/websites/ I have to manually add it**

```
     /* First we need to get the protocol the website is using */
    $protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"], 0, 5)) == 'https' ? 'https://' : 'http://';

    /* returns /myproject/index.php */
    $path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    /*
     * returns an array with:
     * Array (
     *  [dirname] => /myproject/
     *  [basename] => index.php
     *  [extension] => php
     *  [filename] => index
     * )
     */
    $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
    $directory = $path_parts['dirname'];
    /*
     * If we are visiting a page off the base URL, the dirname would just be a "/",
     * If it is, we would want to remove this
     */
    $directory = ($directory == "/") ? "" : $directory;

    /* Returns localhost OR mysite.com */
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    $baseurl = $protocol . $host . "/websites/andrewhunter/";
```

?>

Comment: what's the content of $path_parts when you run the script on the remote server? Depending on the configuration of the webserver, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] might not be the one you're looking for. I suggest checking the contents of $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] also.

Comment: You can check this link, maybe it's what you need.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399720/translate-physical-path-to-virtual-path-in-php

Answer (score 0):

why that part with `$path_parts`? I'm a bit confused by your question, but I understand you basically want to have what's written in the browser's address field? this works on my remote as well as on my local MAMP, may the file be at first or fourth level in my folders

```
 /* First we need to get the protocol the website is using */
$protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"], 0, 5)) == 'https' ? 'https://' : 'http://';

/* returns /myproject/index.php */
$path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

/* Returns localhost OR mysite.com */
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$baseurl = $protocol . $host . $path;

echo $baseurl;
```

Comment: http://localhost/website/home/index.php/images/logo.jpg is what it does now. What I need is for it to go up a few directories now, dynamically. Such as "/website/images/logo.jpg" but for every page, even sub pages like /website/folder/sub-folder/

Comment: So the main issue is I need this: $baseurl = $protocol . $host . "/website/client/"; but even on pages for the navigation, images, etc. to all work. Stylesheets I am using import to fix those and it works fine. So I have a style.css in each sub-sub folder /website/client/folder/sub-folder/style.css (with import to real css)

Comment: Was reading about $path = substr( __FILE__, strlen( $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] ) );

$url = "www.mydomain.com{$path}";